# Noise image compression

Tags: image, compression, noise

I have "noise" image... what is the best way to compress this image ? It can be little lossy. Techniques based on DCT and Wavelet are bad for this sort of problem.
My idea was to generate some recreatable noise and then store only differences... but I cant find any solution for recreatable noise images.

Image example:

[image: Example of noise image]

Comment: What do you know about such noise? Do you know its mean/distribution? You could denoise -> compress denoised via DCT/wavelets -> reproduce noise, but of course you won't be sure the "new" noise to be consistant with the original one.

Comment: Its obtained from original image by taking every f(x) pixel (f(x) is my function)... I dont need to have same noise as result... I want to have something very simmilar (And than I can save only differences, that should be small)

Comment: I presume you mean it can be a little _lossy_, not lossless.  You can't be a "little" lossless.  Either you are or you aren't.

Comment: If you claim to accept lossy because you think you can then send the differences, which "should be small", then you are not accepting lossy.  You are in fact requiring lossless.  The differences won't be small, in that for true noise, they will get you back to the original size or larger.

Comment: By the way, your example image looks like it could be an image with significant vertical correlations if the lines were lined up correctly.  How exactly was this image made?

Comment: Yeah.. sorry... I meant little lossy. Image is made from picture by taking every n-th pixel value, where n is output from spline-fitting of image data (with acceptbale error in brightness).

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's almost the definition of noise to **not** be compressible.

This statement applies to "real noise", when there is no known correlation between the perceived output and another applicable rule. So if your image is just that, or built to look like it is, then sorry, it's not compressible.

Comment: If loseless.. than yes, it almost uncompressible... I mean little lossy... it was language mistake in original post.