# Pattern image compression / generation

Tags: image, design-patterns, compression

What is best way to compress losslessly image with certain pattern. I want the smallest possible size, ideal would be something, that can generate pattern like in image (or very close one and then store just differences):

[image: noise]

It looks sort of like a carpet design. I already posted similar topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14140808/noise-image-compression), but now i have image with pattern.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the size of the pattern beforehand, you could start by just compressing that pattern and adding a couple of numbers indicating to the pattern is replicated. In the example image you show, one would just add how many times the pattern is repeated along each dimension.

Otherwise, if you have no previous information other than the image consists of a smaller image pattern which repeats itself several times, it is quite trickier.

For this particular case where the pattern image is just tiled a number of times, you could first calculate the FFT of the image. As a result you get peaks shifted from each other the same distance in your frequency domain as in your spatial domain. You extract those peaks, and then you know the frequency with which the pattern repeats itself, that is, the size of the pattern. Finally, you crop a rectangle from the image and use it as the generating pattern.